# jQuery sortable (johnny) bootstrap 3 navbar issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-sortable

I've got an issue in with the bootstrap nav sortable in bootstrap 3.

```
$(".nav").sortable({
    group: 'nav',
    nested: false,
    vertical: false,
    exclude: '.divider-vertical',
    onDragStart: function($item, container, _super) {
        $item.find('.dropdown-menu').sortable('disable');
        _super($item, container);
    },
    onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {
        $item.find('.dropdown-menu').sortable('enable');
        _super($item, container);
    }
});

$(".dropdown-menu").sortable({
    group: 'nav'
});
```

Here is a fiddle to just show you what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpv1t4gq/1/

As you try to drag a link around (you can see it best with contact) it's not relative to the cursor.

I've been playing around with it for the past few days but I can't get it to work...

Anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, what I meant by johnny is the jquery plugin made by johnny on github.

https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/

There's also jQuery UI Sortable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue few hours ago and made it! 
Hope it helps.

First you need to edit 2 functions in jquery-sortable.js:

```
onDrag: function ($item, position, _super, event) {
        x = $("#VerticalSort").val();
        if (x == 0) {
            $("#VerticalSort").val(position.left);
            position.left = 0;
        }
        else {
            position.left = position.left - x;
        }
        position.top = 0;
      $item.css(position)
    },

 onDrop: function ($item, container, _super, event) {
        $("#VerticalSort").val("0");
      $item.removeClass(container.group.options.draggedClass).removeAttr("style")
      $("body").removeClass(container.group.options.bodyClass)
    },
```

i used a hidden input in my view just for test the solution, but the idea is to keep the first-click value for substract later and reset to 0 in drop action.

```
<input id="VerticalSort" type="hidden" value="0" >
```

the problem is that in some point JS are doubling the first click values of x/y (named "left" and "top" in the js code)

Hope it Works for you.

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and you need to include the parameter: `delay` > `0`. Ex:

```
$(".nav").sortable({
    group: 'nav',
    nested: false,
    vertical: false,
    exclude: '.divider-vertical',
    delay: 5,
    onDragStart: function($item, container, _super) {
        $item.find('.dropdown-menu').sortable('disable');
        _super($item, container);
    },
    onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {
        $item.find('.dropdown-menu').sortable('enable');
        _super($item, container);
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't see any noticeable difference in the fiddle with and without your "delay: 5" parameter.